# Upload HTML file to AWS S3 and then serving it instead of downloading

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, server

I am downloading a web page and then I am writing to a file named `thisArticle.html`, using the below code.

```
var file = fs.createWriteStream("thisArticle.html"); 
var request = http.get(req.body.url, response => response.pipe(file) );
```

After that I am trying to read file and uploading to S3, here is the code that I wrote:

```
fs.readFile('thisArticle.html', 'utf8', function(err, html){

  if (err) { 
    console.log(err + "");
    throw err; 
  }

  var pathToSave = 'articles/ ' + req.body.title +'.html';

  var s3bucket = new AWS.S3({ params: { Bucket: 'all-articles' } });

  s3bucket.createBucket(function () {
    var params = {
      Key: pathToSave,
      Body: html,
      ACL: 'public-read'
    };

    s3bucket.upload(params, function (err, data) {

      fs.unlink("thisArticle.html", function (err) {
        console.error(err);
      });

      if (err) {
        console.log('ERROR MSG: ', err);
        res.status(500).send(err);
      } else { 
        console.log(data.Location);
      }

      // ..., more code below

    });

  });

});
```

Now, I am facing two issues:

The file is uploading but with 0 bytes (empty)
When I am trying to upload manually via S3 dashboard is uploaded successfully but when I tried to load the URL in the browser it downloads the HTML file instead of serving it.
Any guides if I am missing something?

Answer (score 10):

Set the ContentType to "text/html".

```
s3 = boto3.client("s3")
s3.put_object(
        Bucket=s3_bucket,
        Key=s3_key,
        Body=html_string,
        CacheControl="max-age=0,no-cache,no-store,must-revalidate",
        ContentType="text/html",
        ACL="public-read"
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your upload function is deleting the file with `fs.unlink` before it gets uploaded.  That's why its going up as 0 Bytes.

Also, to make the bucket serve the HTML, you need to turn on webserving as described in the AWS S3 Docs.  http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/UG/ConfiguringBucketWebsite.html

Comment: I commented the fs.unlink still is going up as 0 Bytes. @michael-j