# How to upload a html file in s3 via Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

So, I am trying to upload an HTML file to my `Aws s3`, the file is getting uploaded but it doesn't render as HTML file in the browser.

```
  def upload_coverage_s3
   path_to_file = Rails.root.to_s+'/public/coverage/index.html'
   file = File.open(path_to_file)
   aws_path = "test_coverage/#{Time.now.to_i}/index.html"
   uploadObj = AwsHelper.upload_to_s3_html(aws_path,file)
   uploadObj[:url]
  end



   def self.upload_to_s3_html(path,file)
     if path.nil? || path.blank?
      puts 'Cannot upload. Path is empty.'
      return
     end

     obj = S3_BUCKET.objects[path]


     obj.write(
        file: file,
        content_type: "text/html",
        acl: :public_read
      )

     upload = {
       url: obj.public_url.to_s,
       name: obj.key
      }

    upload
  end
```

All I am getting a white screen with a loading gif

[image]

I followed this link

> [Upload HTML file to AWS S3 and then serving it instead of downloading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45889262/upload-html-file-to-aws-s3-and-then-serving-it-instead-of-downloading)

As I want similar functionality `uploading HTML file and then serving as an HTML file instead of downloading`

**PS:** 
 I uploaded that HTML file manually also in my s3 bucket, the issue is the same.
 How to resolve that.
 Does s3 doesn't support HTML file upload?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are only uploading an HTML file and no other dependencies.

It seems you are uploading a test coverage results. Usually index.html is just the entry point and you have a lot more files generated by your test coverage tool.

You need to upload all other resources and depending on how are they loaded it may or may not work.